# Restar el valor anterior dentro de una fila y acumularlo en otra matriz en R

Tags: r, loops, matrices

Mi intención es para una matriz dada, recorrer la fila y a cada valor `[i,j]` restarle el valor `[i,j-1]`. Una vez recorrida, si el valor es negativo, lo acumula en `[i,2]` y si es positivo en `[i,1]`.

Expongo un ejemplo:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F
(0,1,3,2,4,5)
(2,9,7,3,4,6)
(5,9,4,3,0,1)
```

el resultado espero que sea la suma de hacer (ejemplo solo con fila1):

fila1: `1-0=0; 3-1=2; 2-3= -1; 4-2=2; 5-4=1`

```
X,Y
(5, -1)
(10, -6)
(5, -9)
```

Espero que me podáis ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediante `loop` tal como pides, se puede resolver de la siguiente forma:

```
m <- matrix( c(0,1,3,2,4,5,2,9,7,3,4,6,5,9,4,3,0,1), ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
m

new_m <- matrix(nrow=nrow(m), ncol=2)

for (row in c(1:nrow(m))){
    new_row <- c()
    for (col in c(2:ncol(m))){
        new_row <- c(new_row, m[row, col]- m[row,col-1])
        new_m[row, 1] <- sum(new_row[new_row>0])
        new_m[row, 2] <- sum(new_row[new_row<0])
    }
}

new_m
```

La matriz inicial sería esta:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    3    2    4    5
[2,]    2    9    7    3    4    6
[3,]    5    9    4    3    0    1
```

Y el resultado final:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6   -1
[2,]   10   -6
[3,]    5   -9
```

Revisa la primer fila de tu resultado esperado, por que no es 5 sino 6.

Los `loops` suelen tener un impacto negativo en cuanto a performance, por lo que si es posible, puede ser conveniente trabajar directamente sobre los objetos y no tener que iterar sobre cada fila / columna. La siguiente es una forma más compacta de resolver tu pregunta

```
m <- matrix( c(0,1,3,2,4,5,2,9,7,3,4,6,5,9,4,3,0,1), ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
m

final <- m[,-1] - m[,-ncol(m)] 
new_m <- matrix(c(rowSums(final * as.numeric(final>0)),rowSums(final * as.numeric(final<0))), ncol=2) 
new_m
```

Explicación:

- `m[,-1] - m[,-ncol(m)]` resta dos versiones de la misma matriz, la primera sin la primer columna y la segunda sin la última, esto es básicamente restar una celda por la anterior en cada fila. Nos quedamos con una matriz que tiene una columna menos que no usaremos

  ```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,]    1    2   -1    2    1
  [2,]    7   -2   -4    1    2
  [3,]    4   -5   -1   -3    1
  ```
- Por último `matrix(c(rowSums(final * as.numeric(final>0)),rowSums(final * as.numeric(final<0))), ncol=2)` genera una nueva matriz con la suma de las filas (`rowSums`) cuyos valores son positivos y cuyos valores son negativos.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la colaboración